# PHP Adding database result to multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm trying to generate a multidimensional array like this in PHP :

```
$books =  array(

    "8" => array(   "my girl" => 2.5, 
                    "the god delusion" => 3.5,
                    "tweak" => 3, "the shack" => 4,
                    "the birds in my life" => 2.5,
                    "new moon" => 3.5),

    "14" => array(    "the last lecture" => 2.5, 
                      "the god delusion" => 3.5,
                      "the noble wilds" => 3, "the shack" => 3.5,
                      "the birds in my life" => 2.5, "new moon" => 1)
     );
```

from a database table which is like this :

```
ID  value   title
------------------------------------------------------------------
8   5   Clara Callan
8   5   Where You'll Find Me: And Other Stories
8   5   The Middle Stories
8   5   Jane Doe
8   6   The Witchfinder (Amos Walker Mystery Series)
8   6   More Cunning Than Man: A Social History of Rats an...
8   7   Goodbye to the Buttermilk Sky
9   6   Beloved (Plume Contemporary Fiction)
12  10  If I'd Known Then What I Know Now: Why Not Learn f...
14  5   Mary-Kate &amp; Ashley Switching Goals (Mary-Kate ...
14  5   Tell Me This Isn't Happening
14  6   Flood : Mississippi 1927
16  9   Airframe
17  7   Death in the Clouds
17  5   Bant/Spec.Last of the Breed
17  6   Piercing the Darkness
17  3   Prophet
19  7   Prague : A Novel
```

I'm already tried several ways but I still can't figure out how to do exactly like that. I've been searching numerous threads in here but still no one discussing about this. I'm a newbie in PHP, so I don't understand too much array concept in PHP. Currently my PHP code is like this :

```
        $result = mysql_query($mySelectQuery) or die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        $books = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $userID = $row{'User-ID'};
            $books[$userID] = array($row{'Book-Title'} => $row{'Book-Rating'},);
        }
```

That code already produce similar result with "what I want", but it's still replace the existing book records, so in the end every user only have one book record in their array. My question is:

How could I populate a multidimensional array formatted like mine with the result of my query?

Thanks a million in advance for your answers. And sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query($mySelectQuery) or die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $books = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $userID = $row{'User-ID'};
        $books[$userID][$row{'Book-Title'}] = $row{'Book-Rating'};
    }
```

This will assign your book title as a array key/index, and set the rating as it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop add:

`$books[$userID] = array();`

Inside the loop use:

`$books[$userID][] = array($row{'Book-Title'} => $row{'Book-Rating'},);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

`$books[$userID][] = array($row{'Book-Title'} => $row{'Book-Rating'},);`